# Integration testing process for big applications

Tags: java, integration-testing

I've started to learn about approaches to integration testing in big enterprise applications (java based, spring, and everything :) ).

So I saw two main approaches:

- Running parts of spring context substituting real data parts with in-memory implementation. A drawback of such an approach I guess is that its very hard to maintain these tests, because every test will require sophisticated setup of spring context hierarchy. I understand the ratio to use an in-memory implementation for various databases/external systems, but in this case it looks like a mock and I'm not sure whether its possible at all in the common case.
- Running the whole spring context without the REST front end. Spring will load one time for all the tests in the module and they'll run.
  This method looks better in a sense that I don't need to fiddle with spring contexts and do beans overriding, however it looks like tests can "overlap" and break isolation.

So basically I'm looking for advice - whether its acceptable to use mocks/in-memory implementations in the integration tests, what approach is taken in other organizations, and so forth. Maybe there are other approaches for running integration tests. Please share the experience

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: I would start with the assumption that *the Spring Framework is already fully tested.*  That ought to reduce your testing scope significantly.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not going to test any thirdparty including spring of course. I'm talking solely about testing the project I'm working on